# Apply css to multiple html files without adding path in HTML

Tags: html, css

I have about 2,000 html files that I need to add this css to:

```
 @media print {
        @page {
            size: letter landscape;
            margin: 4cm 4cm 4cm 4cm;
        }
    }
```

I understand that I can just manually go into every HTML file and add the path to the CSS file then it would be included. However that would take a long time. So if there is a faster way to add that css code to every HTML file that'd be awesome!

Comment: Run a batch `find & replace` operation that targets all HTML files in your directory. What IDE do you use?

Comment: Any common js file in oll those ?

Comment: @Aziz I use webStorm

Comment: @NalinAggarwal I'm not sure I haven't looked at all 2,000 files